# Why does Gimp say it needs Windows XP Service Pack 2 when I have XP Service Pack 2?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, gimp, service-pack

I am trying to install Gimp 2.8.0 on Windows XP.  I get an error message "This version of Gimp requires Windows XP with Service Pack 2, or a newer version of Windows."  But when I check my Windows version with Help -> About Windows, it says I have Windows XP Professional Service Pack 2.  Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is incorrect. Gimp 2.8.0 requires XP service pack **3** or later. This bug was fixed in later builds (by correctly saying that SP3 was required). You can see the link with the correct requirements on the [GIMP download page](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/).

> [GIMP for Windows (version 2.8.0)](http://gimp-win.sourceforge.net/stable.html) - 72.7 MB
>   GIMP requires Windows XP with Service Pack 3, or a newer version of Windows to run.